# Why was `git-subtree` removed from the git-scm book?

Tags: git, git-subtree

When looking for documentation on `git-subtree` my search engine will show links to https://git-scm.com/docs/git-subtree, however when I visit that link I'm redirected to https://git-scm.com/docs.

What happened to subtree? Is is deprecated or is this just a mistake? If it's deprecated, is there an announcement with rationale and a suggestion for what might replace it (e.g. are there plans to bring in [`git-subrepo`](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo))?

Comment: For anybody looking, Debian still has the man page: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-man/git-subtree.1.en.html

Comment: I'm away from my laptop; last I heard `git help subtree` still worked, right ? (note: it opens the manage)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git-subtree` is a contrib command: https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/subtree. Therefore it is not part of git's core. The documentation on https://git-scm.com is built from core git and does not include contrib software. This can be slightly confusing since package maintainers often distribute contrib software with the system `git` package.

This must be my search engine trying to be smart and show `https://git-scm.com/docs/{search-term}` when users search for something that looks like a git command, like `git-*`.

Comment: Note that on the Git mailing list, people have reported bugs in `git subtree` (some of these may even have reproducers) but nobody has done anything about fixing them. It seems to be abandonware at this point. It's a bit of a shame since it does things that would be nice to have, but I'm not volunteering to work on it myself... 